# Открыть balloon у оверлея созданного с помощью LoadingObjectManager

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Всем добрый вечер, использую yandex map api 2.1 в приложении на reactjs. Есть карта, на которой отрисовываются точки. Точек много поэтому гружу их как-то так:

```
const loadingObjectManager = new ymaps.LoadingObjectManager(poiService.getPoiUrl(onlyOffices),
{
  clusterize: true,
  clusterHasBalloon: false,
  geoObjectHideIconOnBalloonOpen: false,
  geoObjectBalloonContentLayout: getBalloonContentLayout(ymaps, dispatch, getState),
  geoObjectBalloonPanelMaxMapArea: 0,
  geoObjectBalloonCloseButton: false,
  balloonOffset: [5,-38],
  geoObjectBalloonMaxHeight: 558,
});
map.geoObjects.add(loadingObjectManager);
```

Все отлично работает, при клике на метку получаю заветный balloon.

Появилась необходимость из отдельного react-компонента-списка стучаться в карту при клике на элемент и показывать balloon конкретного оверлея.

Полазил по документации, но так и не смог найти ничего подходящего. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно вызвать этот balloon?

Answer (score 0):

Работа с balloon в LoadingObjectManager аналогична ObjectManager, посмотрите вот это пример https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager_balloon